# play-silhouette: specify body parser for (Un)SecuredAction?

Tags: scala, authentication, playframework, playframework-2.0, silhouette

I'm using silhouette for authentication in a play web application and want to do something like this:

```
def action = UnsecuredAction(BodyParsers.parse.json).async { implicit request => 
    // use json 
}
```

This seems to be possible when using Play's build-in `Action`, but not  with silhouette's `UnsecuredAction` and `SecuredAction`. Is there a way to do this without having to fall back to silhouette's `(Un)SecuredRequestHandler` or having to check manually if the body is actually JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse your request body to JSON by using `async(parse.json)`.

For example:

```
def index = silhouette.SecuredAction.async(parse.json) { implicit request =>
   // Write your code here...
}
```